# Python Post - keep getting response 400, but curl works

Tags: python, curl, sonarqube, python-requests

I have a simple python 3 script that send a post request to delete a project in SonarQube. While I am keep getting  in my python script, a simple curl commands works... any idea what is wrong with my python script?

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=',
}

files = [
    ('key', 'com.eclipseoptions.viewserver:viewserver:feature_VS-313-add-an-instruction-event-and-view'),
]

r = requests.post('http://devsonar/api/projects/delete', headers=headers, files=files)
print(r)
```

The following curl command works fine:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -F "key=com.eclipseoptions.viewserver:viewserver:feature_VS-313-add-an-instruction-event-and-view" "http://devsonar/api/projects/delete"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python requests is really a good library. Files option in post is used to upload file and I don't think `com.eclipseoptions.viewserver:viewserver:feature_VS-313-add-an-instruction-event-and-view` is a file if so, you have to read the file in binary mode and then send it like `files = {'key': open(filename, 'rb')}`. so the code should be:

```
import requests
files = {'key': open(filename, 'rb')}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='}
response=requests.post(url,files=files)
```

[check this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) for details on uploading files using requests library in python.

If it is not a file you can send the payload directly as a dictionary like this:

```
import requests
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='}
data = {'key': 'com.eclipseoptions.viewserver:viewserver:feature_VS-313-add-an-instruction-event-and-view'}
response=requests.post(url,data=data,headers=headers)
```

[check this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) for details on sending payload.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used data, not files, as an input to the python script, this should work:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=',
}

files = [
    ('key', 'com.eclipseoptions.viewserver:viewserver:feature_VS-313-add-an-instruction-event-and-view'),
]

r = requests.post('http://devsonar/api/projects/delete', headers=headers, data=files)
```